# Conflicting rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several rewrite rules that are listed below

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.html?$ php/statePage.php?region_slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-tree-services/([^/\.]+)\.html?$ php/cityPage.php?region_slug=$2&state_slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-tree-services/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)\.html?$ php/vendorPage.php?slug=$3&region_slug=$2&state_slug=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-Sitemap\.xml?$ php/xmlState.php?region_name=$1  [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.html?$ php/otherPages.php?pageSlug=$1  [L]
```

The first four work properly however the last rewrite rule displays the template for the `statePage.php` file not the `otherPages.php` file.

Comment: Have you noticed your first and last rule are the same? which why your last rule never happens? You will need something else on the Rule to make clear when it should go to statepage and when it should go to otherpages

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how to write another rule that still works properly but is different from the others.